# How to detect the uploaded file type in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-type

I have an form to upload only image file using angularJS. Uploading the file is all working fine. The problem is, I want to restrict the uploaded file to be only image file and also the size of the image to be some MB. How can I achieve this using only angularJS? Below is the code

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post("logoTypesServiceStore", fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success( function(data) {alert(data); }).error( function(data) { alert(data)});

};
```

Below is the form to upload file.

```
 <form name="logoTypeForm" novalidate>
     <input type="text" name="logoType" ng-model="logoType" class="form-control" required />
     <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modern browsers have File API [support](http://caniuse.com/fileapi).

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    files[0].type; //MIME type
    files[0].size; //File size in bytes
};
```

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image) is a list of image MIME types

Comment: Hii @LostInComputer... am new to Angular JS.. can you please tell me briefly, how to use these to validate file extension and file size ??

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to already specify the files you would like to accpet within your `input` tag like so:

```
<input type="file" name="files" accept="image/*">
```

For more information check out the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) reference for the input tag.

Comment: not a good idea for 100%: user could rename it's hacky file to myFile.jpg
also browser will still have option in select type "all files"