# How i can restrict some file formats to be upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using angular file upload (nv-file-select) to upload file, now my question is how can i restrict some file formats so that user can only see files with doc/docx and xls/xlsx format.

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="vm.uploader"
            name="uploadFile"
            id="file1"
            ng-model="vm.fileInfo.filename"
            ng-click="vm.onFileClick()" / >
```

Please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect the uploaded file type in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158365/how-to-detect-the-uploaded-file-type-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

Just try with adding filters:

```
$scope.vm.uploader.filters.push({
    name: 'fileFormatFilter',
    fn: function(item, options) {
        var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
        return '|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```

Comment: nope, i still can upload with others format when i change from `"Custom FIles"` to `"All Files"`